# Linkedin skills data using omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, linkedin-api

I am trying to fetch linkedin data of user using `omniauth` and `omniauth-linkedin`.

For skills I am getting data like `#<Hashie::Mash id=16 skill=#<Hashie::Mash name="AJAX">>, #<Hashie::Mash id=17 skill=#<Hashie::Mash name="Linux">>, #<Hashie::Mash id=18 skill=#<Hashie::Mash name="Apache">>, #<Hashie::Mash id=19 skill=#<Hashie::Mash name="RSpec">>, #<Hashie::Mash id=20 skill=#<Hashie::Mash name="JSON">>...`

I have following in my `omniauth.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :linkedin, Settings.linkedin_key, Settings.linkedin_secret, 
           :scope => 'r_fullprofile r_emailaddress r_network', 
           :fields => ["id", "email-address", "first-name", "last-name", 
                       "headline", "industry", "picture-url", "public-profile-url", 
                       "location", "skills", "date-of-birth", "phone-numbers",        
                       "educations", "three-current-positions" ]
end
```

For skills **I need skills with proficiency** as shown here http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields#skills

Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Did you solve this? Having a similar issue

Comment: Did you find out how to achieve this? Having a similar issue here. If yes please share.